# 64 bit Declare, PrtSafe?

Tags: excel, vba

I got an email from a colleague that could not install one of my Macro.
He got a new computer and it seems it has a 64 bit version of Excel.

The error is on this line:

```
Private Declare Function apiCopyFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "CopyFileA" _
  (ByVal lpExistingFileName As String, _
  ByVal lpNewFileName As String, _
  ByVal bFailIfExists As Long) As Long
```

and the error message says this line has to be updated to be used in 64 bit system using PrtSafe attribute.

I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/shared/compatibility-between-the-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-office

And if I understand this correct the new code should be:

```
#if VBA7 then
   Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiCopyFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "CopyFileA" _
      (ByVal lpExistingFileName As String, _
      ByVal lpNewFileName As String, _
      ByVal bFailIfExists As Long) As Long
#else
   Private Declare Function apiCopyFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "CopyFileA" _
      (ByVal lpExistingFileName As String, _
      ByVal lpNewFileName As String, _
      ByVal bFailIfExists As Long) As Long
#end if
```

Since I can't test the code myself I just wanted to know if I got it correct.
Is the code snippet above compatible with both 32 and 64 bit versions so that I don't have to maintain two versions?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thank you! Not sure how you could compose an answer but I will accept it when I see it. Need to go now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#If VBA7` will be `True` for any recent Office VBA host application, but that doesn't account for x86 or x64 bitness.

Use `#If Win64` to determine the bitness of the host application.

`PtrSafe` is will compile in VBA7 regardless of the bitness.

`Long` integers in 32-bit hosts work for everything, but in a 64-bit host a `Long` integer might get truncated, which often translates into the sudden, fiery death of the host EXCEL.EXE process.

My understanding is that this would be fully compatible between 32 and 64 bit hosts, across VBA6 and VBA7, on Windows:

```vb
#If VBA7 then
'Office 2013 & above
    #If Win64 Then
    'x64 host
       Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiCopyFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "CopyFileA" _
          (ByVal lpExistingFileName As String, _
           ByVal lpNewFileName As String, _
           ByVal bFailIfExists As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    #Else
    'x86 host
       Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiCopyFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "CopyFileA" _
          (ByVal lpExistingFileName As String, _
           ByVal lpNewFileName As String, _
           ByVal bFailIfExists As Long) As Long
    #End If
#Else
'Office 2010 & under:
   Private Declare Function apiCopyFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "CopyFileA" _
      (ByVal lpExistingFileName As String, _
       ByVal lpNewFileName As String, _
       ByVal bFailIfExists As Long) As Long
#End If
```