# PtrSafe sub declaration?

Tags: excel, vba

I asked a similar question a few months ago:
[64 bit Declare, PrtSafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66889003/64-bit-declare-prtsafe)

And figured I could use the same code here but it did not work.
This is the "old" code:

```
Private Declare Sub GetLastInputInfo Lib "User32" (ByRef plii As LASTINPUTINFO)
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
```

And I made it:

```
#If VBA7 Then
'Office 2013 & above
    #If Win64 Then
    'x64 host
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As LongPtr
        Private Declare PtrSafe Sub GetLastInputInfo Lib "User32" (ByRef plii As LASTINPUTINFO)
    #Else
    'x86 host
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
        Private Declare PtrSafe Sub GetLastInputInfo Lib "User32" (ByRef plii As LASTINPUTINFO)
    #End If
#Else
'Office 2010 & under:
    Private Declare Sub GetLastInputInfo Lib "User32" (ByRef plii As LASTINPUTINFO)
    Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
#End If
```

But it didn't work either.

The error message the user got the first time was this:

[image]

It says it's a compile error and I need to update the code with PtrSafe method.
And my code to fix it did not work. The user says it's the same error, but I can't confirm it since I don't have a x64 computer.

Where did I go wrong in the declaration of the sub?
The code works on x86 computers.

This failed too:

```
#If VBA7 Then
'Office 2013 & above
    #If Win64 Then
    'x64 host
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As LongPtr
        Private Declare PtrSafe Sub GetLastInputInfo Lib "User32" (ByRef plii As LASTINPUTINFO)
        Private Type LASTINPUTINFO
            cbSize As LongPtr
            dwTime As LongPtr
        End Type
    #Else
    'x86 host
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
        Private Declare PtrSafe Sub GetLastInputInfo Lib "User32" (ByRef plii As LASTINPUTINFO)
        Private Type LASTINPUTINFO
            cbSize As Long
            dwTime As Long
        End Type
    #End If
#Else
'Office 2010 & under:
    Private Declare Sub GetLastInputInfo Lib "User32" (ByRef plii As LASTINPUTINFO)
    Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
    Private Type LASTINPUTINFO
        cbSize As Long
        dwTime As Long
    End Type
#End If
```

Complete module code as it is now:

```
'Private Type LASTINPUTINFO
'  cbSize As Long
'  dwTime As Long
'End Type

#If VBA7 Then
'Office 2013 & above
    #If Win64 Then
    'x64 host
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As LongPtr
        Private Declare PtrSafe Sub GetLastInputInfo Lib "User32" (ByRef plii As LASTINPUTINFO)
        Private Type LASTINPUTINFO
            cbSize As LongPtr
            dwTime As LongPtr
        End Type
    #Else
    'x86 host
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
        Private Declare PtrSafe Sub GetLastInputInfo Lib "User32" (ByRef plii As LASTINPUTINFO)
        Private Type LASTINPUTINFO
            cbSize As Long
            dwTime As Long
        End Type
    #End If
#Else
'Office 2010 & under:
    Private Declare Sub GetLastInputInfo Lib "User32" (ByRef plii As LASTINPUTINFO)
    Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
    Private Type LASTINPUTINFO
        cbSize As Long
        dwTime As Long
    End Type
#End If

'
'Private Declare Sub GetLastInputInfo Lib "User32" (ByRef plii As LASTINPUTINFO)
'Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long



Function IdleTime() As Single
  Dim a As LASTINPUTINFO
  a.cbSize = LenB(a)
  GetLastInputInfo a
  IdleTime = (GetTickCount - a.dwTime) / 1000
End Function

Sub Form_Timer()

    LR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inaktivitet").Cells(Sheets("Inaktivitet").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(UCase(Environ("UserName")), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inaktivitet").Range("B21:B" & LR), 0)) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    
    tme = IdleTime
    Debug.Print tme & " " & Now()
    
    
    If tme >= ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inaktivitet").Range("E14").Value * 60 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ThisWorkbook.Close
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5), "Form_Timer"
End Sub
```

So it runs the form_timer every five seconds and if above a threshold it will save and close the workbook

Comment: I think I found the error, I have sent out a new version to the user to test. The declaration of the type at the top of the image has "Long". I think it should have been included in the #IF and be LongPtr

Comment: `GetTickCount` returns a Long. There is a `GetTickCount64` version that returns a `LongLong` if you really need that, but then you could end up with different results on different Office versions.

Comment: Gah! Ok.. What would the difference be. The code is supposed to be an inactivity timer and self close the workbook if opened for an extended time.

Comment: GetTickCount would roll over back to 0 after about 50 days I think.

Comment: Ok.. That shouldn't be an issue. If you're inactive in 50 days then you should be fired in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should need is:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub GetLastInputInfo Lib "User32" (ByRef plii As LASTINPUTINFO)
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
    Private Declare Sub GetLastInputInfo Lib "User32" (ByRef plii As LASTINPUTINFO)
#End If
```

Comment: I will try that too if that is wrong what I found. See the comment above. I was so focused on the declaration of the sub that I forgot the type.

Comment: Before I send this version, do you think I need the GetTickCount64 or should the GetTickCount function work on x64 computers?

Comment: `GetTickCount` should work too.

Comment: This did not work either.

Comment: What does that mean **exactly**?

Comment: The workbook won't open since this is part of the workbook_open sequence. The timer starts when workbook opens and checks every five seconds if it should close or not. But since there is a compile error on this module it won't open correctly. The workbook itself probably opens but the timer does not start (if you end the VBA code that is running). But it's hard for me to know more exactly what is happening since I can't test it myself. I can only relay what the users say

Comment: They shouldn't be getting a compile error with that code. Are you sure that is what is causing the error?

Comment: I have two people now with this error, I will try and ask the other to not bother the same all the time. But I just had an idea. Can the timer be limited to an integer instead. That still gives about nine hours, plenty enough. Is that a possibility? Can the tickcount be truncated to fit a integer to make it "work", because integers does not have x64 issues. Or have I misunderstood the problem here?

Comment: You have misunderstood. :) By the way, the Type definition should have remained the same as in the original code. I have tested the code on a 64bit system and it does not error.

Comment: It was. I had cbSize and dwTime as Long. only the two lines of sub/function declarations was changed to the seven lined version you posted in the answer.

Comment: I finally got it sorted. It was another declaration in a different module that was the issue. But the users only looked at the error message and not where the error was pointing. Which is understandable, and my fault for not checking the other modules. Thank you for the help!